# Can't reset password

Tags: linux, debian, password

I am currently using a Debian 10 linux VM from Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I changed the configuration to require a password when I use the `sudo` command, but I forgot to actually set up a password first. So now I can't `sudo` because I don't actually know the password.

```
sudo passwd
sudo -i
```

I can't use any of these because I don't actually know the password. I tried to use GCP options to reset the password but I can't because they are telling me I'm not the administrator.

What can I do reset and change the password?

Comment: You need to get Google Support to help you. We can't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only Google Support can help you reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud Platform's options to reset the password may actually attempt to use `sudo` within the VM to perform their task. So with your change, you have effectively lost your administrative access.

About the only way to fix this without contacting Google Support would be to set up a second VM, terminate this problem VM (possibly forcefully), and then present the problem VM's disk to the new VM as a second disk.

Then you could login to the second VM, mount the disk of the first one to `/mnt` or similar temporary location to gain access to it, and then fix the configuration. After doing just that, you can stop the second VM, return the disk back to the first VM, start the first VM and verify it works. If it does, you can delete the second VM.